# Failed to resolve dependency while sync with gradle in Android studio 1.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I just met this error while trying to sync gradle after add a new line in my app gradle file:

compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'

The error is shown as below:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration.
>        Required by:
>            PalmHeart:app:unspecified
>   Failed to list versions for com.umeng.analytics:analytics.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/umeng/analytics/analytics/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/umeng/analytics/analytics/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8087 refused

And I think it might be something wrong with my http proxy, you can check this picture below:

[image]

And here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mzzo.palmheart"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
    compile project(':FloatingActionButton')
    compile files('libs/andbase.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/umeng-update-v2.6.0.1.jar')
}
```

I searched a lot in google but still can't figure out why, hopefully I could find the answer here.

Many thanks.

Comment: Remove line and build/sync again to make sure it is that line causing the issue

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle files please

Comment: After remove this line gradle works fine, but when I tried to add a compile '' line the same error showed again. I wonder there is something wrong with my http proxy.

Comment: I have this problem too, any solution?